# Issues with printing structs in C

Tags: arrays, c, loops, for-loop, struct

I'm incredibly new to this and have a school assignment I have to write a gradebook program that uses a custom struct to hold student IDs and grades. I have been trying unsuccessfully for days to figure out why it will not print properly, or when it does print (after a lot of shifting things around) it only prints the second set of input.

The gradebook.h section is the custom structure.

```
// gradebook.h

struct gradeID
{
    int id;
    char grades[25];
};
```

```
// Gradebook.h is a header file to define
// a global structure.
    
#include "gradebook.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
    
void sort(struct gradeID *, int);
    
int main(void)
{
    // Variables and structure definitions
    int ctr;
    char contInput;
    int i;
    struct gradeID grade;
    struct gradeID *identifier;
    int *temps;
    
    // Allocates 10 integers worth of memory for the program to use.
    // If there is not enough memory, the program will print an error
    // statement and terminate the program.
    temps = (int *) malloc(10 * sizeof(int));
    if (temps == 0)
    {
        printf("Not enough memory!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    
    // Prints basic instructions for the program
    printf("\t\tGradebook Recorder\n");
    printf("Input student IDs and grades.\n");
    printf("These will be sorted by ID and printed.\n");
    
    
    /* Creates a for loop that will continue until the program
       hits the designated number of array elements. For the sake
       of expediency, I have set this amount to 10, but it can be
       changed as necessary.*/
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        printf("Input student ID:\n");
        scanf(" %d", &grade.id);
        printf("Input grade:\n");
        scanf(" %s", grade.grades);
    
        // This allows early exit of the program
        printf("Do you have more grades to enter?\n");
        printf("Y/N\n");
        scanf(" %c", &contInput);
    
        if(contInput == 'N' || contInput == 'n')
        {
            printf("Finalizing and printing input-\n\n");
            break;
        }
    
        ctr++;
    }
    
    printf("Grades Sorted by Student ID:\n\n");
    printf("\tStudent ID: Student Grade: \n");
    
    for(i = 0; i < ctr; i++)
    {
        printf("\t%d", grade.id );
        printf("\t%s", grade.grades);
    }
    
    identifier[i] = grade;
    
    return(0);
    
    free(temps);
}
    
void sort(struct gradeID identifier[], int counter)
{
    int inner;
    int outer;
    struct gradeID temp;
    
    // Loops for sorting
    for(outer = 0; outer < counter - 1; ++outer)
    {
        for(inner = outer + 1; inner < counter; ++inner)
        {
            if(identifier[inner].id < identifier[outer].id)
            {
                temp = identifier[inner];
                identifier[inner] = identifier[outer];
                identifier[outer] = temp;
            }
        }
    
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: `free(temps)` will never be executed since it's after `return`. Why don't just just use a normal array `int temps[10];` instead of `malloc()`?

Comment: You never allocated any memory for `identifier`, so assigning to `identifier[i]` is undefined behavior.

Comment: You allocate memory for `temps` but you never use it. What is it for? Did you get confused between `temps` and `identifier`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pointer `identifier` is uninitialized

```
struct gradeID *identifier;
```

So this statement

```
identifier[i] = grade;
```

independent on the value of `i` invokes undefined behavior.

In this for loop

```
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    printf("Input student ID:\n");
    scanf(" %d", &grade.id);
    printf("Input grade:\n");
    scanf(" %s", grade.grades);

    // This allows early exit of the program
    printf("Do you have more grades to enter?\n");
    printf("Y/N\n");
    scanf(" %c", &contInput);

    if(contInput == 'N' || contInput == 'n')
    {
        printf("Finalizing and printing input-\n\n");
        break;
    }

    ctr++;
}
```

you are entering new data in the same object `grade` of the structure type. So the new data overrides the previous data stored in the object.

Moreover the variable `ctr` was not initialized

```
int ctr;
```

So this statement in the above for loop

```
ctr++;
```

also invokes undefined behavior.

The variable `temps` that points to a dynamically allocated array

```
temps = (int *) malloc(10 * sizeof(int));
```

is not used.

This statement

```
free(temps);
```

never gets the control because before it there is the return statement

```
return(0);

free(temps);
```

What you need is to define an array of the type `struct gradeID` as for example

```
struct gradeID grades[10];
```

and fill it with values.